# Twitter Oauth GMT / BST problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth

I keep getting 401 when trying to login via Oauth with Twitter.

I'm using twitter_oauth-0.3.3 with oauth-0.3.6 in rails

It used to work perfectly some time ago, so after some digging, I realised it might have something to do with my timezone.

In the headers of the Twitter response, one of them is:

```
date: 
- Sun, 11 Apr 2010 16:53:34 GMT
```

Even though the time is actually 17:53:34 BST

I'm assuming the request is signed using BST time, and so it fails.

Anyone had this problem / found a fix for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth timestamp used in the signature is in the [epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format.

You might want to inspect the `Authorization` request header, check for the **oauth_timestamp** and check what you are sending with this helpful [online tool](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

The difference between your epoch time and Twitter's (which you get in the response, as you wrote) should be in the +- 300 second frame.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, it turned out that the time wasn't being calculated correctly when the request was generated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the time is 17:53:34 BST, then it really **is** 16:53:34 GMT.

So, if the oauth library you're using can't cope with the server specifying the time in a different time-zone (are you *certain* that's what's causing the problem) then it could be a bug in the library.

(Not very helpful, I know - I don't use ruby and haven't done any oauth development myself.) Have you tried contacting the library developer(s)?